# Calculating the minimum element in an array

Tags: c, arrays, minimum

I've written a little program to determine the minimum element in an array `a[]`. When I debug, the program seems to be working fine initially but then the for loop in the `min()` function stops execution after two steps, despite the array being of size 10.

The final output is 23, when it sould be 3.

Is the code `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)` incorrect? I found it on another [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) on stackoverflow.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int min(int[]);

int main(){
    int a[]={100,23,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    printf("%d", min(a));
    return 0;
}

int min(int a[]){
    int min = INT_MAX, i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
        if((i>=0) && (a[i]< min))
            min = a[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer. Doing `sizeof` on a pointer only gives you the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

Comment: No it's not correct in this case. See the second answer on the question you linked.

Comment: @Luke Collons: As Joachim Pileborg mentioned in comment just find size of array using `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` and pass it to `min` function as second argument and use it in `min` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function, `a` is a pointer to integer array, so `sizeof(a)` returns the size of a pointer which is typically 4 or 8 bytes depending on the system. Saying that, it is not possible to count the number of elements in a C array using `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` inside the function. You need to pass the number of elements explicitly as an argument to the function.

```
int min(int a[], int n) {
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {...}
    ...
}

printf("%d", min(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])));
```

Comment: Downvoted, because this question has already been answered in more depth in other questions.

Comment: You say: *a is a pointer to integer array*`, but a` is not a pointer to an integer array.

Comment: @user694733, I wrote the answer before seeing the duplicate link. Not sure whether that is enough reason to down vote.

Comment: @2501 what do you mean by `a` is not a pointer?

Comment: That is not what I wrote.

Comment: @2501 I didn't get what you mean. It would have been more helpful to me if you described in more depth.

Comment: You wrote: *`a` is a pointer to integer array* , but `a` is not a pointer to an integer array.

Comment: @2501 Then what is `a`?

Comment: @user694733 You kind of people are virus in this site

Comment: @ZainFarooq With my voting I try to encourage people in certain direction. Feel free to hate me for it, but please remember that I do not hate this answer; I simply think that closing as a dupe was more appropriate than giving answer. Downvotes should not be taken as a personal insult.

Comment: This is not my question or answer but I have experienced you people. You people discourage others to ask questions and make answers here. You have a lot of knowledge but you are arrogant of it and you misuse your voting here. @user694733

Comment: @ZainFarooq As I said, I want to encourage people to read existing answers as they are quite complete already. I don't downvote just to make myself feel better. If you want to discuss this further, create a [chat room](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) for it. In the mean time, please avoid [name-calling](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).